yacc returns without parsing full sentence
I am currently trying to write a parser in lex and yacc to parse all valid time formats. The relevant .l and .y codes are included below.
^[0-9]{1,2}  { printf("HOUR: %s\n", yytext); return HOUR; }
:            { printf("COLON\n"); return COLON; }
[0-9]{2}     { printf("MINUTE: %s\n", yytext); return MINUTE; }
am           { printf("AM\n"); return AM; }
pm           { printf("PM\n"); return PM; }
\n           { printf("EOF\n"); return EOF_; }
.

%token HOUR COLON MINUTE AM PM EOF_
%%

main: time EOF_ { printf("The time format is correct\n\n"); }

time: HOUR ampm
    | HOUR COLON MINUTE
    | HOUR COLON MINUTE ampm
    ;

ampm: AM
    | PM
    ;

The problem is that it will correctly work the first time, parsing after reading the whole line, and then incorrectly read tokens the next time, and then it will again read properly the next time.
12:00                                                                                                                                 
HOUR: 12                                                                                                                              
COLON                                                                                                                                 
MINUTE: 00                                                                                                                            
EOF                                                                                                                                   
The time format is correct                                                                                                            
                                                                                                                                      
5am                                                                                                                                   
HOUR: 5                                                                                                                               
Incorrect time format: syntax error

AM
Incorrect time format: syntax error

EOF
Incorrect time format: syntax error

5am
HOUR: 5
AM
EOF
The time format is correct

Here is the main function in the yacc file for reference:
int main() {
  do {
    yyparse();
  } while (!feof(yyin));
}

It would be great if anyone can help me understand what mistake I am doing.

I am confused by your example test session; you enter 5am twice but get different output.

That is what confused me as well. The first time, the parser seems to return after parsing individual tokens but not the full line, but the second time, it parses the full line before returning. This keeps happening alternatingly.

Sounds like a state issue then; you'll probably want to terminate the process after every parse test or find some way of doing a yyrestart().

You need to enable tracing to see what state you are in when the error occurs.
